# Why do I get quite a few lines of 'declare -x' everytime I open my terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Since around Thursday last week I have been getting a load of `declare -x` lines printed in my terminal. The terminal works fine however its quite frustrating to see. I've been on a couple threads on here and they didn't really help for my issue.

I am on Ubuntu.

```
declare -x CLUTTER_IM_MODULE="xim"
declare -x COLORTERM="truecolor"
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x DISPLAY=":0"
declare -x GDMSESSION="ubuntu"
```

There are lot more lines than that but that's just an example.

Comment: Do you have `set -x`  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed  anyware in your startup files?

Comment: I don't think so, how would I check?

Comment: Check each of the startup files listed in [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) for your shell.

Comment: Been through all the files listed on that website, couldn't find a `set -x` print command. I'm suspecting i messed up when installing Firefox Dev Edition.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by wrong export syntax in one or more of your bash startup files (`/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`).

To see the contents of your `.bashrc` run `cat ~/.bashrc`.

Look for a sole `export` in a line:

```
export
```

The existence of such line suggests that maybe the next line misses `export`. In other words maybe the two lines should be one. If you see

```
export
some_variable="some value"
```

then ask yourself if `some_variable` should be exported. Probably it should be like this:

```
export some_variable="some value"
```

but a newline character has been inserted by mistake. This issue is common when people install `firefox-dev`. In their `~/.bashrc` they have

```
export
PATH=/opt/firefox/firefox:$PATH
```

while it should be a single line:

```
export PATH=/opt/firefox/firefox:$PATH
```

(Note in general [`.bashrc` is not a good place to manipulate `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476922).)

Comment: Thanks! My english and technical skill to explain are very low. But now that answer look so beautyfull!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was facing the same issue.
In simple terms, if you want to solve this issue as mentioned above first find the line break by running cat ~/.bashrc.

then run the following commands
nano ~/.bashrc
[You will see something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOSmy.png)

then go to the line break and remove it

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

then press <kbd>Y</kbd> for confirmation
and at the end press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
for confirmation.